# Problems writing to USB drive from _www process

Tags: c, macos, permissions, usb

I have a macOS C program which is a helper app. It runs as root and has sticky permissions.

One of the jobs of this program is to backup files to an external USB drive.

When I run the program from a terminal window... it works perfectly.

However, when invoked via a web admin page (eg., via the web server), it fails to run with an "operation not permitted".

This is on the latest macOS.  I've set the drive to be "ignore ownership on this volume".   The drive in /Volumes is also 777.

So... when the process is invoked via the web, the user/group is both _www.  It appears that no matter what, the process invoked via _www can't write to the USB stick.

To be more specific... it can't create any new files.  It CAN overwrite existing ones.  It can't mkdir either.

I've googled my brains out and no solutions seem to work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the solution here.

Open System Preferences and go to Security/Privacy and then click Full Disk Access from the left side and enable the httpd access from the right side.

Thanks!